# LinkButton in GridView redirecting to same page in Old browser (Works fine in chrome)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, linkbutton

I am trying to redirect the LinkButton in my GridView to a different URL. But whenever I click on it from Chrome or Firefox it works fine and redirects me to intended URL. But same thing in Old Browser redirects to same page URL without redirecting to new URL.

Following is the code

**GetContent.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="SearchCatResGridView" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server" 
            ShowHeader="true" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="2" 
            CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="-1" GridLines="None" CssClass="DataTable" BorderWidth="1" 
            PagerSettings-Visible="false" 
            OnRowDataBound="fileGridView_RowDataBound" >
<columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Register">
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton Forecolor="#F37F0F" runat="server" ID="linkButton2" OnClientClick="SetTarget();"
                        oncommand="Button1_Command"  
                        Text="Learn More/ Register" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("userid")%>'>
        </asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**GetContent.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    string url = generateLmsSsoUrl(@"course/" + value);

    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this since it looks like its not working only on old browser.
TIA

Comment: The problem is that the old Browser cannot handle both "OnClientClick" and the (postback) oncommand="Button1_Command".  It is only executing the client side code and posting back to same page. Why don't you try to redirect using the same (client side) function  SetTarget()"

Comment: @DaniDev I will try to remove OnClientClick and will check if it works

Comment: what does "SetTarget();" do?

Comment: Just Curious? Is this issue resolved was my suggestion helpful? if so I can add it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="myLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="myLinkButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("userid")%>'>Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

protected void myLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string userid = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
            Response.Redirect("~/HereURL/course/" + userid);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkshow" runat="server" OnCommand="showDetails" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userid")%>'>Click Me</asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected void showDetails(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
     string userid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     Response.Redirect("course/"+userid);
}
```